# Select current ( week or any given week ) records excluding week ends and holidays

Tags: php, sql, date, mysqli

I have two database tables a **to_do** table and a **holidays** table.
Both tables have a **date** column.
**to_do** table has column **hours**.
I need to get sum of hours for current week or the week for a given date but excluding week ends and the days in **holidays** table.

Here are my tables `SQL`

```
CREATE TABLE `holidays` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `to_do` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `hours` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

enlighten me with the best possible solution/query pls, Thank You.

Comment: Side note: Why is `date` an `int` in one table like the other? any special reason?

Comment: that is by mistake sorry. now corrected

Comment: Ok. See the answer below; looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For weekdays only use the `DAYOFWEEK` function. The sum and more filters are left as an exercise for you, but the gist is:

```
SELECT * FROM to_do
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(`date`) IN (2,3,4,5,6)
AND `date` NOT IN (
  SELECT `date` FROM holidays
)
```

`DAYOFWEEK` function documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: Thanks @CodyCaughlan